# Change application label during Ant build in Android

Tags: java, android, ant, command-line

I am trying to rename my Android application during Ant build through command line. I want to do this as I want to create different versions of same app for different environments (testing, pre-live, staging, etc). I am able to change the package name, versionName, versionCode which allowed me to install all the variants on a single device. Now I need to change the name of the app, which comes from

```
android.label
```

in AndroidManifest.

I tried the following in my custom_rules.xml, but it didn't work

```
<target
    name="-pre-build"
    depends="-custom-manifest-version" >
</target>


<!-- change the version name and label for the application -->

<target name="-custom-manifest-version" >


    <replaceregexp
        byline="true"
        file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match="android:versionName=&quot;/*.*&quot;"
        replace="android:versionName=&quot;${app.newversionname}&quot;" >
    </replaceregexp>

    <replaceregexp
        byline="true"
        file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match="android:label=&quot;/*.*&quot;"
        replace="android:label=&quot;${app.newappname}&quot;" >
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

but this is not helping, the app crashes on launch.

I tried commenting the lines

```
 <replaceregexp
        byline="true"
        file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match="android:label=&quot;/*.*&quot;"
        replace="android:label=&quot;${app.newappname}&quot;" >
    </replaceregexp>
```

And it works fine; that means there is something wrong with these lines.

Comment: I suggest that you consider moving to [Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), as Ant support is fading away.

Comment: I would love to do that.. but dues to legacy.. I cant...